# How to send a form to my e-mail by googlescript every tuesday and every thrusday?

Tags: forms, schedule

First of all I'm completly new at programming so I think my question is really simple but i couldn't find an answer that really matches my issue.

I created a form in googleforms and I want to send this form to my e-mail every tuesday and every thursday by googlescript. (the embed form, not the link)

Firstly, I'm not beeing successful not even sending it to my e-mail.

I tried two methods that I found here but thats what I got:

this is the code im using:

```
function sendForm(form,email) {

var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var email = "myemail@gmail.com"
var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();


var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var htmlBody = HtmlService

.createHtmlOutput(response)
.getContent()

; 
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
   subject: "subject",
  htmlBody: htmlBody,
 });


}
```

The other code i tried just give me the e-mail message "HtmlOutput" and not the form.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.